# Getting an Azure role recycled but keeping the same VM

Tags: azure

I know that when running a role in Azure, the VM can be recycled any time (mainly either because you had an uncaught exception or because MS needs to apply an OS update).
My question is, after the recycle, will your role be re-started in the same VM?
I need to run some security tools that use config files generated from the host hardware signature ; so when deploying to a 'new' VM, the tools won't run anymore...

Any clue ? Thanks in advance!
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. when you manually recycle you get the same machine back, but should not rely on that. The VM may be recycled for you due to a catastrophic hardware failure (such as disk failure), in which case you won't see that machine again!

Comment: OK, so that's basically impossible to control... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The correct solution is probably to generate the configuration files in a startup task. Then you won't have to care whether you get the same VM or not.

Comment: Bingo... and be idempotent with your startup tasks.

Comment: That would be an option... if only the generation of these configuration files could be automated. Right now it's a tedious process where the hardware signature needs to be generated on the server, sent to "someone" who will in turn generate an exe that needs ultimately to be executed on the server in order to authorize the tools. So right now I'm discussing with their technical team to check whether they can expose these back and forth through a web service. Thanks anyway for the heads up.